# Confused between octave and python

Tags: python, machine-learning, octave

Recently I have completed ML course in coursera by Andrews Ng. It's an awesome course. I was working with octave through out the course. But, python is much popular when compared to octave. So, I have started to learn python now. I was implementing linear regression using python. In that I am doing nothing. Simply calling the predefined function for linear regression. But, in octave I used to write the code from scratch. I have to find parameters using gradient descent algorithm. But, no such things in python. I have referred the following link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-python-implementation-ae0d95348ac4

My question is, won't we use any algorithms like gradient descent to learn parameter Theta? Is everything is predefined in python?

Thanks.

Comment: you don't want to re-invent the wheel if you know how the wheel is made, do you?

Comment: With over 30 years of Python being used to solve problems, most things will be predefined now since we have had time to learn to solve these problems using python. But if you want you are always re implement the same problems and solve them in a way that works for you if some of the cookie cutter algorithms are robust enough. I've had to a few times.

Comment: You are used to implement something because you were learning the algorithms. Octave has many optimization functions which are more powerful than simple gradient descent. Just use them once youve understand the basics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is a programming language, just like Octave. So everything that can be done in Octave can be done using Python too. If you want to implement `Linear Regression` algorithm from scratch using Python in order to validate your understanding, of course you can do it (I have done it too). Why stop at Linear Regression, you can implement `SVM`, `Decision Trees` or even `Deep Neural Networks` from scratch in Python. And it is a good way to gain concrete understanding of these algorithms.

However, over the years all these have been implemented in Python in libraries like Sklearn etc. So as the complexity and volume of data increases, you would want to use one of these libraries or frameworks. Why? Because these are highly optimized implementations. To get high level feeling - implement Linear Regression using simple list and for loops, and then vectorize it with Numpy, you will see the difference in performance.

So to summarize - if you are curious, go ahead and implement the algorithms from scratch to gain solid understanding. As complexity and data volume will increase, start using the libraries and frameworks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Supratim Haldar. I am clear now. You gave me a very clear point of view. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that it was useful, @ShankarMuthusamy! If you need some reference, you can refer to my Github repository (link is provided in my profile page). And of course there are tons of other very helpful materials on the web.